# How to increase elapsed time for getRelativeDateTimeString method, also how to month name for normal date

Tags: java, android, android-dateutils

I have used [getRelativeDateTimeString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long%29) which is showing the maximum of 1 week elapsed time.

1. How to increase more than 1 week.
2. after the elapsed time it shows the normal date formatting like 11/14/2007, 8:20 AM, I want to show month name in a date like `Nov/14/2007, 8:20 AM` or `14 Nov 2007, 8:20 AM`

I expect output to be: `Nov/14/2007, 8:20 AM`  but the output is `11/14/2007, 8:20 AM`

```
java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) time1 * 1000);
    int flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
    CharSequence mdate = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(context,time.getTime() , DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, flags);
```

Comment: what is your output formate

Comment: the output is "Yesterday, 12:20 PM", "11/14/2007, 8:20 AM" depending on time,  I expect the output month name in 3 digit or full.

Comment: i am talking about mm/dd/yyyy something like that

Comment: Yes, mmm/dd/yyyy  or dd/mmm/yyyy , just month like mmm, Thanks

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Is there any solution or alternate? please tell.

Comment: see my answer this is one of an alternate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break it into two parts:

1. get the date in your desired format using `DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");`
2. get the time elapse using `getRelativeTimeSpanString`

hope it helps, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following class can be used to extract a date from a timestamp:

```
public class DateUtils {

public static final String DF_dd_MM_yyyy = "dd/MM/yyyy";
public static final String DF_MM_dd_yyyy = "MM/dd/yyyy";
public static final String DF_MMM_dd_yyyy = "MMM dd,yyyy";
public static final String DF_dd_MMM_yyyy = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
public static final String DF_MMMM_dd_yyyy = "MMMM dd, yyyy";
public static final String DF_MMMM_dd_yyyy_AT_hh_mm_a = "MMM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a";
public static final String DF_dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
public static final String DF_HH_mm_a = "HH:mm a";
public static final String DF_hh_mm_a = "hh:mm a";
public static final String DF_MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_a = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a";
public static final String DF_yyyy_MM_dd__HH_mm_ss = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
public static final String DF_yyyy_mm_dd_T_hh_mm_s = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";//2017-10-10 T 10:10:10

public static final int SPLI_DATE = 101;
public static final int SPLI_MONTH = 102;
public static final int SPLI_YEAR = 103;
public static final String E_MM_DD = "EEEE MM/dd ";
public static final int DAY_SECONDS = 86400;
public static final int HOUR_SECONDS = 3600;
public static final int DAY_MILISECONDS = 86400000;
public static final int HOUR_MILISECONDS = 3600000;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
private String strDateFormat;
private String strTimeFormat;
private String strDateTimeFormat;
private String strStringDate;
private long milliSeconds;
private TimeZone timeZone;

public static long getCurrentTimeInSecond() {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public static long convertMilliSecondToSecond(long milliSeconds) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds);
}

public static long convertMilliSecondToHours(long milliSeconds) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds);
}

private static long getOffsetFromUtc() {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date now = new Date();
    return tz.getOffset(now.getTime());
}


public static class Builder {

    DateUtils dateUtils;

    public Builder() {
        dateUtils = new DateUtils();
        dateUtils.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    }

    public Builder setDateFormat(String strDateFormat) {
        dateUtils.strDateFormat = strDateFormat;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setTimeFormat(String strTimeFormat) {
        dateUtils.strTimeFormat = strTimeFormat;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setDateTimeFormat(String strDateTimeFormat) {
        dateUtils.strDateTimeFormat = strDateTimeFormat;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setSeconds(long seconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = seconds * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setTimeZone(TimeZone timeZone) {
        dateUtils.timeZone = timeZone;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setUTCTimeZone() {
        dateUtils.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setStringDate(String strDate, String strDateFormat) throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.strStringDate = strDate;
        dateUtils.strDateFormat = strDateFormat;
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateFormat);
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = dateUtils.dateFormatter.parse(dateUtils.strStringDate).getTime();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setStringTime(String strDate, String strTimeFormat) throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.strStringDate = strDate;
        dateUtils.strTimeFormat = strTimeFormat;
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strTimeFormat);
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = dateUtils.dateFormatter.parse(dateUtils.strStringDate).getTime();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder setStringDateTime(String strDate, String strDateTimeFormat) throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.strStringDate = strDate;
        dateUtils.strDateTimeFormat = strDateTimeFormat;
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateTimeFormat);
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = dateUtils.dateFormatter.parse(dateUtils.strStringDate).getTime();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder now() {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addHour(int hour) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds += hour * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addMinutes(int minutes) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds += minutes * 60 * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addSeconds(int seconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds += seconds * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addMiliSeconds(int milliSeconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds += milliSeconds;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder minusHour(int hour) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds -= hour * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder minusMinutes(int minutes) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds -= minutes * 60 * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder minusSeconds(int seconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds -= seconds * 1000;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder minusMiliSeconds(int milliSeconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds -= milliSeconds;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStringDate() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateFormat);
        return dateUtils.dateFormatter.format(getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public long getDateInSecond() throws ParseException {
        /*if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dateUtils.strDateFormat))
            dateUtils.strDateFormat = DateUtils.DF_dd_MM_yyyy;
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateFormat);
        Date date = dateUtils.dateFormatter.parse(dateUtils.dateFormatter.format(getMilliSeconds()));
        return date.getTime() / 1000;*/
        return (getMilliSeconds() - (getMilliSeconds() % DAY_MILISECONDS)) / 1000;
    }

    public long getHourInSecond() throws ParseException {
        return (getMilliSeconds() - (getMilliSeconds() % HOUR_MILISECONDS)) / 1000;
    }

    public Date getDate() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateFormat);
        return new Date(getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public String getStringTime() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strTimeFormat);
        return dateUtils.dateFormatter.format(getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public Date getTime() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strTimeFormat);
        return new Date(getMilliSeconds());
    }
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    public String getSpitedDate(long timestamp, int type) {
        Calendar cal = null;
        try {
            cal = new Builder().setSeconds(timestamp).getCalendar();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch (type) {
            case SPLI_DATE:
                return cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "";
            case SPLI_MONTH:
                SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
                return month_date.format(cal.getTime());
            case SPLI_YEAR:
                return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "";

        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getStringDateTime() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateTimeFormat);
        return dateUtils.dateFormatter.format(getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public Date getDateTime() throws ParseException {
        dateUtils.dateFormatter = getSimpleDateFormatInstance(dateUtils.strDateTimeFormat);
        return new Date(getMilliSeconds());
    }

    public Calendar getCalendar() throws ParseException {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeZone(dateUtils.timeZone);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(getMilliSeconds());
        return cal;
    }

    public long getMilliSeconds() {
        return dateUtils.milliSeconds;
    }

    public Builder setMilliSeconds(long milliSeconds) {
        dateUtils.milliSeconds = milliSeconds;
        return this;
    }

    public long getDateTimeStampInSecond() {
        return convertMilliSecondToSecond(dateUtils.milliSeconds);
    }

    public long getUTCDateTimeStampInSecond() throws ParseException {

        return ((dateUtils.milliSeconds - getOffsetFromUtc()) / 1000);
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat getSimpleDateFormatInstance(String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf.setTimeZone(dateUtils.timeZone);
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        return sdf;
    }

}
```

The following snippet shows how you can use the class:

```
 String date = new DateUtils.Builder().setSeconds(timeStamp).setDateFormat(DateUtils.DF_MMMM_dd_yyyy_AT_hh_mm_a).getStringDate();
```

Comment: This works as an alternate, not the exact. will somehow manage to solve my problem. thanks for the solution.